# Print CSS - a full page for an element

Tags: css, printing

Is there some syntax I can use in my `media="print"` CSS which will make one div element cover an entire printed page?

```
<div id="important_thing">Important!</div>
<ol id="other_stuff">
  <li>Thing</li>
  <li>blah</li>
</ol>
```

**print.css**

```
#important_thing {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#other_stuff li {
  float:left;
  width:20pt;
  height:8pt;
}
```

This doesn't have the desired effect. I'd like to have an entire page for 'important stuff' and as many other pages as required for all the list elements.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html

Comment: for what purpose this media="print" is using . for print format??

Comment: When you include CSS in an HTML document you can specify the medium on which that CSS should apply: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" media="screen" />` or `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="both.css" media="screen,print" />` or `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="forprinters.css" media="print" />`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a *page-break-after*

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

```
#important_thing { 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
  page-break-after:always 
}
```

You may have to combine it with a *page-break-before:always*

Comment: width: 100vw; height: 100vh;

Comment: @tomorrow__ Thank you. If you make that a reply I will upvote it.

Comment: This inserts a page break after the element, but it does *not* make the element cover an entire page. The size of the element is untouched which can be checked e.g. by applying background color to it.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by tomorrow__, this can be achieved by applying

```
width: 100vw; height: 100vh;
```

to the element.