# How do I print a page (height 100% , width 100% )?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when print the page on (`<body onload="window.print()">`) the page is not complete.

How do I print a page (height 100% , width 100% )?

I need your help in solving this problem

[image: this pic]

```
<html dir="rtl">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <style type="text/css">
    @page {
      size: A4 landscape;
    }

    @media print {

      body,
      html,
      #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

    body,
    html {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="window.print()">
  <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:1100px;height:750px;border-style:outset;overflow:hidden">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print CSS - a full page for an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832187/print-css-a-full-page-for-an-element)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
    @page {
        margin: 0cm;
    }
```